# Proving the equivalences of three statements regarding projections.

Tags: functional-analysis, projection

> Let $\mathcal H$ be a Hilbert space and $P$ be a linear operator on $\mathcal H.$ The the following statements are equivalent $:$
>
> $(1)$ $P^2 = P = P^*.$
>
> $(2)$ The space $\mathcal  K = \{x\ : Px = x \}$ is a closed subspace of $\mathcal H$ and $\text {Ker}\ P = \mathcal K^{\perp}.$
>
> $(3)$ $P^2 = P$ and $\|P\| \leq 1.$

I have managed to prove $(1) \implies (2)$ and $(1) \implies (3).$

For $(1) \implies (2)$ let us first take $x \in \text {Ker}\ P.$ Then for any $y \in \mathcal K$ we have $$\langle x, y \rangle = \langle x,Py \rangle = \langle Px, y \rangle = 0$$ which shows that $x \in \mathcal K^{\perp}$ and hence $\text {Ker}\ P \subseteq \mathcal K^{\perp}.$ Conversely, let $x \in \mathcal K^{\perp}.$ Then for any $y \in \mathcal K$ we have $\langle x,y \rangle = 0.$ But since $y \in \mathcal K$ we have $Py = y.$ Hence we have $$\langle Px,y \rangle = \langle x, Py \rangle = \langle x,y \rangle = 0,\ \ \text {for all}\ y \in \mathcal K.$$ Now since $P^2 = P$ it follows that $Px \in \mathcal K.$ So by putting $y = Px$ in the above equation we find that $\|Px\|^2 = 0 \implies Px = 0.$ Hence $x \in \text {Ker}\ P.$ Therefore $\mathcal K^{\perp} \subseteq \text {Ker}\ P.$

Combining this with the above inclusion we have $$\mathcal K^{\perp} = \text {Ker}\ P.$$

To prove that $\mathcal K$ is closed we first note that $$\langle x, Px \rangle = \langle x, P^2 x \rangle = \langle Px, Px \rangle = \|Px\|^2.$$ Hence by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality it will follow that $\|Px\| \leq \|x\|.$ Hence $P$ is a bounded linear operator with $\|P\| \leq 1.$ Now given a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ from $\mathcal K$ converging to $x \in \mathcal H$ we have $x_n=Px_n \to Px.$ Hence by the uniqueness of the limit it follows that $Px = x$ and hence $x \in \mathcal K.$ This proves that $\mathcal K$ is a closed subspace of $\mathcal H.$ This proves $(1) \implies (2).$

The last paragraph of the above proof also proves $(1) \implies (3)$ as a bi-product.

From here how do I prove the equivalence of the given three statements? Can anybody help me proving $(2) \implies (3)$ and $(3) \implies (1)\ $?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easier implications to prove are $(3) \Rightarrow (2)$ and $(2)\Rightarrow (1)$.

$(3)\Longrightarrow (2)$ Assume $P^2 = P$ and $\|P\|\leq 1$. The first condition means that $P$ is a projector : we have $\mathcal K = \ker(p-\text{id}) = \operatorname{im}(p)$ and $\operatorname{im}(p) \oplus \ker (p) = \mathcal H$.
Since $p-\text{id}$ is bounded, its kernel $\mathcal K$ is a closed subspace of $\mathcal H$.

Let $x\in \mathcal K$ and $y\in \ker p$. Then, for any $\lambda \in \mathbb R$.
\begin{align}
\|x\|^2 &=\|p(x)\|^2 \\
&= \|p(x+\lambda y)\|^2 \\
&\leq \|x+\lambda y\|^2 \\
& \leq \|x\|^2 + 2\lambda\langle x,y\rangle + \lambda^2\|y\|^2\\
0& \leq 2 \lambda \langle x,y\rangle + \lambda^2 \|y\|^2
\end{align}
This can only be true for all $\lambda$ is $\langle x,y\rangle =0$. Therefore, $\ker p \subset \mathcal K^\perp$. Since they are closed and $\ker p \oplus \mathcal K = \mathcal H$, we get $\ker p = \mathcal K^\perp$

$(2)\Longrightarrow (1)$  Assume $\mathcal K$ is closed and $\mathcal K^\perp = \ker p$. In this case, we have $\ker p \oplus \mathcal K = \mathcal H$. For any $x\in\mathcal H$, we can write it uniquely as $x = y + z$ with $y\in\ker p$ and $z\in\mathcal K$. Then, $p(x) = p(y)+ p(z) = z$. We see that $p^2(x)= p(z) = z = p(x)$ ie $p^2 = p$.

Last, let $x = y+z$ and $x' = y' + z'$ be two vectors written like before. Then :
\begin{align}
\langle x,p(x')\rangle &= \langle y+z,z'\rangle \\
&= \langle z,z'\rangle \\
&= \langle z,y'+z'\rangle\\
&=\langle p(x),x'\rangle
\end{align}
so $p^* = p$.

Comment: How do you get $\|x\|^2 = \|Px\|^2$ unless you asumme that $P$ is self-adjoint? $(3)$ doesn't give you self-adjointness of $P.$ Right?

Comment: For $(2) \implies (1)$ we have another issue. You have claimed $\text {Ker}\ P \oplus \mathcal K = \mathcal H.$ For that you need to show that $x- P(x) \in \mathcal K^{\perp} = \text {Ker}\ P.$ How do you know that unless $P$ is idempotent? $(2)$ doesn't assume idempotence of $P.$ Right? I am not fully convinced with your argument. Please don't mind.

Comment: For the first question, I use $x = Px$ since $x\in \mathcal K$. For the second, I use the fact that for a closed subspace of a Hilbert space we have $F\oplus F^\perp = \mathcal H$.

Comment: Here I am assuming that $\mathcal H$ to be a complex Hilbert space. Then $$\|x + \lambda y\|^2 = \|x\|^2 + \lambda \langle x, y \rangle + \overline {\lambda} \langle y,x \rangle + |\lambda|^2 \|y\|^2.$$ From here the above inequality becomes $$|\lambda|^2 \|y\|^2 + \lambda \langle x, y \rangle  + \overline {\lambda} \langle y,x \rangle \geq 0$$ which can also be written as $$|\lambda|^2 \|y\|^2 + 2\ \mathfrak R \left ( \lambda \langle x,y \rangle \right ) \geq 0.$$ From here can we also conclude that $\langle x, y \rangle = 0\ $?

Comment: Yes I got it. What I did is as follows $:$ Let $\langle x, y \rangle \neq 0.$ Then there exists $s \gt 0$ and $\phi \in [0,2\pi)$ such that $\langle x, y \rangle = s\ e^{i \phi}.$ Let us take $r,\theta \in \Bbb R$ in such a way that $\|y\| \lt \sqrt {\frac {2s} {r}}$ and $\theta + \phi = \frac {3 \pi} {2}.$ Let $\lambda = r e^{i \theta}.$ Then from the above inequality it follows that $r^2 \|y\|^2  - 2rs \geq 0.$ In other words $\|y\|^2 \geq \frac {2s} {r},$ a contradiction.